# What is the difference between GMM and MLE?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I am studying different machine learning algorithms currently and can't quite see the difference between *Gaussian Mixture Modelling* and *Maximum Likelihood Estimation*.

Is *GMM* only a special case of *MLE* using the gaussian distribution as an estimation function?

Comment: In general they are different concepts. The MLE is for arbitrary distributions. What similarities do you have in mind ?

Comment: GMM uses a product of gaussian distributions to determine the maximal probablity of a classification.
MLE uses a set of gaussian distributions (or other distribution functions) but determines the classification solely according to the distribution with the highest probability.
So one is _winner takes it all_, the other one is a _product over all_ to classify a measurement?

Comment: @Jonas you need to specifically say what you find similar. To people that know the difference your question is like asking "what is the difference between cats and crocodiles" like they are both animals (in your context machine learning/statistic tools) and sometimes MLE uses Gaussians, but beyond that, why on earth would you even set up an equivalence between them? It seems really really strange. Thus, we really need you to clarify your question say exactly what things about them you find remotely similar. I don't even know where to start pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 1):

GMM is a specific way to model data. It does so by fitting, unsurprisingly, a Gaussian mixture to the data. Essentially, you learn or fit a parameter set $\Theta$ that describes the data probabilistically (or statistically). 
Generally, assuming the data are in dimension $n$, $\Theta$ includes $k$ weights 
(i.e. $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^k$, each component giving the weight of each mixture), as well as $\mu_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ for $i\in[1,k]\subset\mathbb{Z_+}$. Then you can do things like generate new data that looks like the input, classify/cluster new data, etc...

But how to get $\Theta$? The answer is to use [expectation maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Description) (EM). Essentially, the idea is to iteratively alternate between:

(1) Given $\Theta_t$, estimate the likelihood of the data $X$ (with tags $Y$) via $\mathcal{L}(\Theta|X)=P(X|\Theta)$ and the *expected* log-likelihood 
$\mathcal{E_t}(\Theta)=\mathbb{E}_{Y|\Theta_t}[\ln\mathcal{L}(\Theta|X,Y)]$.

(2) Find a better model by maximizing the parameters as 
$\Theta_{t+1}=\arg\max_\Theta \mathcal{E_t}(\Theta)$ and goto (1).

Notice that this algorithm is very general, and can be used for fitting many different models (e.g. [GMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Gaussian_mixture)). But it itself is not a model.

---

Summary: GMM is a specific *model*; EM is an *algorithm*.